# which sorting algorithm is fast on structure arrays with unique elements in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting

I have an array of a structure which is supposed to store unique character strings. Which sorting algorithm is best suited for such requirements.

Here is the structure

```
strcut info
{
unsigned char key[33];
unsigned int size;
};
```

Stability is not an issue because the sorting should be done only on **key** and it is guaranteed that no two keys will have the same value.

EDIT:

While looking for sorting algorithms i read that pointers make it much faster for the sorting algorithm. And considering the huge size of the array I would be happy to have it. But i dont know if i have to change the structure for that to happen.

The size of the array is expected to be between 1000 and 2000 and the distribution of its elements is totally random.

Comment: You wont get more than "any generic sorting algorithm" given the requirements. And this probably what you should use.

Comment: It also depends on how many elements you expect to have, and whether they are expected to start out nearly in-order or quite randomly ordered.

Comment: These are only guidelines:

 - For small lists use insertion sort.
 - For medium sized do quicksort.
 - For large lists do bucket sort (for example per character, separate backet for each ascii value).

Comment: Are you looking for [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say [quick sort](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_sort) or [merge sort](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort) would be your best bet, though depending on the situation, a [insertion sort](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) may work as well. You can read up on other algorithms here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm